# ClickableSpan in RecyclerView not working properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a layout with a `TextView` and a `ClickableSpan` inside it. Clicking on the `TextView` should fire an intent that opens an URL in the browser. Clicking on the `ClickableSpan` should fire a different intent.

Before, I was working with `ListView` and it worked as it should by simple adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the root `ViewGroup`; but when switching to `RecyclerView`, clicking on the `ClickableSpan` fires both intents: the one in the `TextView` and the one in the `ClickableSpan`.

Here's my code:

```
// here i'm just getting the span bounds
int start = link.getStart(); 
int end = link.getEnd();
MyClickableSpan clickSpan = new MyClickableSpan() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        // here i set the intent
    }

};
ssb.setSpan(clickSpan, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
holder.title.setText(ssb, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
holder.title.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

`MyClickableSpan` is a regular `ClickableSpan` but without the underlined text.

Comment: Have you found the answer of this?

Comment: Same question..